# Не работает padding-top и padding-right в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction1() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup-test
   ========================================================================== */

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.popup-container1 {
    background-image: url("https://thealeksuswebstudio.com/wp-content/themes/mylandingpage/img/Vacation.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*margin-top: -2rem;*/
    /*margin-bottom: -2rem;*/
    height: 500px;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: #555;*/
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /*border-radius: 6px;*/
    /*padding: 8px 0;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    /*bottom: 125%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
    /*margin-left: -80px;*/
}
.elementor-element-930ea7d {
    text-align: center;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*padding: 60px 200px 60px 200px;*/
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .popup .show {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        /*padding: 50px 25px 0 30px;*/
    }
}


.popup-img1 {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("https://thealeksuswebstudio.com/wp-content/themes/mylandingpage/img/Vacation.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    /*padding: 300px;*/
    width: 250rem;
}
.popup-background {

}
.popup-content {

}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="popup-test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction1()">
    <div class="popup-container1">
        <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">
            <div class="popup-img1">

            </div>
            <div class="popup-background">
                <div class="popup-content">
                    <h2>Алексей</h2>
                    <h6> КОММЕРЧЕСКИЙ ДИРЕКТОР</h6>
                    <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

При попытке сделать padding модального окна с классом .popup .show срабатывает только padding-bottom и padding-left. Padding-top и padding-right не работают. Если добавить top: 0, то padding-top работает, но padding-right не реагирует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не видите `padding`, поскольку ширина элемента `.popup .show` превышает ширину области просмотра, добавьте `box-sizing: border-box;`, чтобы ширина элемента вместе с `padding` была не более 100% ширины области просмотра.

Ознакомьтесь, как влияет значение `box-sizing` на размеры элементов:

[Box-sizing (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction1() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup-test
   ========================================================================== */

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.popup-container1 {
    background-image: url("https://thealeksuswebstudio.com/wp-content/themes/mylandingpage/img/Vacation.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*margin-top: -2rem;*/
    /*margin-bottom: -2rem;*/
    height: 500px;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: #555;*/
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /*border-radius: 6px;*/
    /*padding: 8px 0;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    /*bottom: 125%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
    /*margin-left: -80px;*/
}
.elementor-element-930ea7d {
    text-align: center;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 60px 200px 60px 200px;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .popup .show {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        /*padding: 50px 25px 0 30px;*/
    }
}


.popup-img1 {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("https://thealeksuswebstudio.com/wp-content/themes/mylandingpage/img/Vacation.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    /*padding: 300px;*/
    width: 250rem;
}
.popup-background {

}
.popup-content {

}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="popup-test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction1()">
    <div class="popup-container1">
        <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">
            <div class="popup-img1">

            </div>
            <div class="popup-background">
                <div class="popup-content">
                    <h2>Алексей</h2>
                    <h6> КОММЕРЧЕСКИЙ ДИРЕКТОР</h6>
                    <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что повлияло на превышение области просмотра? Width же 100%

Comment: @Aleksus значение `box-sizing`, оно по умолчанию имеет значение `box-sizing: content-box`, это означает, что изменение `margin`, `padding` или `border` будет влиять на окончательное значение размеров элемента, почитайте статью, вы сразу всё поймёте, ну и ответ отметьте :)